# measures numeration in polymetre

Tags: meter, polyrhythm

In polymetre and/or poly-tempo music, measures count in staves may be unequal.

How measures should be numerated?

Each stave have separate numeration?

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of measure numbers is to refer to points in the music, for example in rehearsal. In polymeter music where bar lines don't line up between staves/parts, it's hopeless to try to refer to a point in the music by measure numbers.

Use rehearsal letters where things do line up, and don't number the measures at all between them.

Comment: But can't you point by "stave/party name : measure number" ?

Comment: Wait a minute, I maybe misunderstood you. You **DO** number measures, but omit those one that rhythmically don't match?

Comment: I'd agree that rehearsal letters would be the best way to go, as far as being able to instruct an entire group of people on where to start from during the rehearsal.  But I do think it could be valuable to have measure numbers, which I would say should be separate for each separate meter, as that way you (or the conductor) can refer to these measure numbers in providing feedback on moments that don't fall on or near rehearsal letters.